# Vscode peek definition stops working after one/two use/s

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using vscode version 1.51.1 e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f x64 on ubuntu version Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

I am working on C code in Vscode. It has extension C/C++ (C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing.).

The option - peek definition works fine for the first one/two times but then goes away.

Screenshot of peek definition when working:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Screenshot of peek definition on second attempt - not working:

[image: Screenshot 2]

For now, to get the peek definition back, I have to either reload window (ctrl + shift + p -> reload window -> enter) or restart Vscode.

Any idea how to stop the feature from disappearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem persists when symlink is used to open the project in vs code. If the actual path is provided while opening the project, the plugin vscode-cpptools works correctly.

Refer link [issue on github] - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6280